# 'titlecase' pipe not found

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have used the titlecase pipe for formatting in my html. It works fine in the app. But when I run ng test on a service that dynamically creates this component I get error that pipe 'titlecase' could not be found in said component. What is the issue here? I have added the CommonModule to the imports of the service.spec.ts file in TestBed.configureTestingModule but it still gives me the error.

component.html

```html
<div> {{ state | titlecase }}</div>
```

This error is not shown when I run the component.spec.ts file. Only in the service.spec.ts it's giving me the error. Both the service